Sums involving $\exp(-z/n)$
I am interested in knowing if there are known results for an infinite series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\exp(-z/n)$. Any example of this sort for some nontrivial $c_n$ and associated references would be helpful.

I don't know of any important result about that series but we can analyze it as follows.
We know that
$$ e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!} $$
if we replace $z$ by $-z/n$, then
$$ e^{\frac{z}{-n}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{z}{-n})^k}{k!}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(-n)^kk!} $$
then
$$c_n  e^{\frac{z}{-n}} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{(-n)^kk!}z^k$$
then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n exp(-z/n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{(-n)^kk!}z^k$$
then I think we can swap the order of summation (perhaps you can prove it)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n exp(-z/n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_n}{(-n)^kk!}\right)z^k$$
then you would need to prove the convergence of the series $\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_n}{(-n)^kk!}\right)$ for some family of $c_n$ and then prove that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ converges where $a_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_n}{(-n)^kk!}$.
